# How to use VSCode with Twine Snowman

Tags: visual-studio-code, twine-game-engine

I am using Twine 2 with Snowman 2.0.3 to write an interactive novel and I find it extremely hard to use the IDE editor for markdown and Javascript, so I effectively maintain a separate VSCode project where I write all my markdown/code and then copy-paste it to Twine. Is there a way to integrate them, the same way other game engines do (like Unity for example, where you edit your scripts in your editor of choice and they synchronize automatically).

I've seen that the internal representation of my project is a single file but this isn't something I can work with. Ideally, I would like to have each passage and the story JavaScript/CSS in a separate file. Any solutions/ideas?